# Firestore Timeout

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when the internet connection is too poor or might be there are some firewall blocks.

How could I resolve this error:

**[2019-06-22T05:49:47.163Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.5): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. 
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.**

The problem occurs while reading.

**NOTE:** I had checked with a good internet with no additional firewall settings, and there were no issues like this.

I am looking for  a solution which can notify the user for the same.

Comment: Thanks , for the post it help me clarifying some of the things, but it didn't helped me the way I was expecting it to. From the post what I understood  is, there is some sort of writing to the firestore is happening but I was even not able to retrieve the documents(read error) if the internet is slow resulting in blank UI , so any help ?

Comment: while this is a duplicate, it actually may be a specific issue as I am having the same issue - and have for two days (when this was posted). Please open a ticket with Firebase support directly and report the problem.

Comment: Ok , I would post the same , when I  face the issue next time., and just a clarification  although it is marked as duplicate, but I just read the complete original post and it was regarding the write issue , and not the read , so the solutions provided there aren't working in this case. Thanks.